# Make required fields mandatory with asterisk based on a boolean condition

Tags: java, jsf, required

I have a JSF page included with `ui:include` to which I pass two `ui:param`, called **name** and **mandatory**. Inside the included page I use the two params in the following way.

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputText value="#{name}:" />
    <h:outputLabel rendered="#{mandatory}" value="*" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

How can I combine the two paramers into a single value? For example to display the name and the mandatory condition to a panel header.

Comment: is changing `<h:panelGroup>` into `<h:panelGroup rendered=#{mandatory}>` enough ? not sure what you mean...

Comment: I want to display the panel even if it is not mandatory. I have lots of fields/editors where the user can enter/select values. Only some of them are mandatory.

Comment: so why don't you warp the pair of `outputText ` and `outputLabel ` inside another `panelGroup` with `rendered` condition ?

Comment: How do I combine the name with the mandatory information to set the value of the panel's header? For example: <p:panel header="user:*" />.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
<p:panel header="#{name}:#{mandatory?'*':''}" />
```